# C# Running Active Automation Object - How to Source events?

Tags: c#, com, ole-automation, active-objects, running-object-table

I have a (long running) console application, written in C#, which I want to be able to manipulate through COM (so no InProc DLLs and regasm.exe). `IDispatch` is all I need - so a classic OLE Automation object.

Here I'll present a minimal version of what I try to do. I've defined a COM class like this:

```cs
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("9009311a-c0b2-42a4-8e7c-f42091d71594")]
public interface ITestEvents {
    void OnEvent();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ITestEvents))]
public class ComClass {
    public event Action OnEvent;

    public int Test() {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

In `Main()` I simply register the object in the Running Object Table (ROT) with `"comTestApp"` Moniker and sleep the application.
You can see the full source [here](https://pastebin.com/eYfaWDbG).

This works just fine when I try to invoke the object's methods. For example, this VBScript works OK:

```vb
Set obj = GetObject("comTestApp")
WScript.Echo obj.Test() Rem prints 100
```

But when I try to connect the events:

```vb
Set obj = GetObject("comTestApp")
WScript.Echo obj.Test() Rem Works

WScript.ConnectObject obj, "obj_" Rem Fails

Sub obj_OnEvent
    WScript.Echo "Wish it worked"
End Sub
```

I get error on calling `ConnectObject` (error 0x80020009 "Could not connect object").

The same code (only the class GUID/ProgID have to be added) works if I register the assembly as InProc object with regasm.exe but I don't need that. I need access to the running application and that's why I use the ROT.

I created a simple C++ test to see if I can find out more about the problem. The source is [here](https://pastebin.com/879FCkeR). I have written a minimal COM object implementing the `IDispatch` interface which should act as the Event Sink. First I get the object from the ROT, query for the `IConnectionPointContainer`, then get `IConnectionPoint` for `ITestEvents`'s IID and finally call its `Advise()` method. As with VBScript, it fails (although I get another error - 0x80040202). I placed a breakpoint on the `QueryInterface` method of the event sink to see what happens when `Advise()` is called. I can see that `QueryInterface` is called for various interfaces and finally it requests my `ITestEvents`, which I return and set status `S_OK`. But still, the `Advise()` method returns the above error.

I have also tried another thing: I've set the GUID of the `ITestEvents` to `{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` which is the IID of `IDispatch`. And now `Advise()` returns `S_OK`! I have even simulated an event and the `Invoke()` method of the event sink gets called! Alas this does not solve the problem in general. If you request it directly from `IConnectionPointContainer` by IID - you get it, but it seems it is not properly enumerated by `ITypeInfo` and VBScript still does not work.

I have almost no experience with COM so I'm not sure where to go from here. The fact that if I use the `IDispatch` IID makes it work, makes me wonder if some custom Marshaling is needed for the `ITestEvents` interface, although it is pure `IDispatch` so I think it should be handled well by the runtime.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear how OnEvent turned into OnUpdate in the scripting code.  And it is not clear whether obj was properly declared WithEvents.  Nor can we tell if you registered the server with the /tlb option.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, my mistake with the OnEvent/Update. Fixed it. There is no WithEvents in VBScript. No I haven't registered with /tlb, because I wanted the app to be portable exe with no dependency on the registry. But it turned out it is not possible. I've kinda figured it out. Will write my own answer here soon to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is that it is not possible to supply connection sink (to Out of Process object) whose interface IID is not registered in the registry.

It seems that marshaling information is mandatory, in order to send the sink interface to the server. I was hoping that since the C# classes supply full `ITypeInfo`, the COM runtime will figure out that the interface is `IDispatch` type and use a default proxy. Alas, this does not seem to be the case so the only option remains - the registry.

As a bare minimum I found that this is needed:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{9009311a-c0b2-42a4-8e7c-f42091d71594}\ProxyStubClsid32]
@="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
```

This defines our events interface and says that we use for proxy the standard IDispatch proxy.

I've tested this on Windows 7 and 10 and it works! - VBScript can `ConnectObject` and everything works fine.

Accidentally I found a Win7 installation where this did not work (win ver 6.1 build 7601 sp1). It worked only after registering the Type Library (`regasm.exe /tlb`). The installation in question has Windows Updates disabled (my other Win7 is fully updated) so I guess at some point something has been changed, which enables the interface to be marshaled even without type library, based on the fact that we specify the default IDispatch proxy.

Finally, since I wanted to keep my app portable and independent of the registry, I resorted on manual events implementation. Something similar can be seen [here](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/extend_events.aspx?display=Print).